# How to get value in context menu?

Tags: android, android-layout, contextmenu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [get view id from oncontextitemselected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016569/get-view-id-from-oncontextitemselected)

I have list view of items that contains items **id** (as TextView), **name** and **description** which is take from database. When I click and hold a list item it will show the context menu with options `delete` and `rename`.

I have done this code, but the issue is how i get the id from `id textView` in `contextmenu onContextItemSelected()`?

Answer (score 0):

You get the `MenuItem`, right? It has the `getItemId` Method. This might be what you want?

Further on, `MenuItem.getMenuInfo()` returns an AdapterContextMenuInfo (Cast needed). That in turn has a `position` field. With that psotiion, you can `get` the View.

Comment: i want item id which is pulled from db and attached to list as text view so that i can delete specific item from list