# Retrieving id of a TextView in LinearLayout on which a context menu was opened

Tags: android

I am programmatically filling a LinearLayout with TextViews in which I put text based on entities that are filled from the database and user preferences.

I am now trying to add a context menu on each of these TextViews to allow the user to delete that particular entry (and thus object, and thus db row).

I can get long presses to open a contextmenu, but I see no way to get the id of the TextView that is associated with the menu.

Virtually all the information on this references ListViews (which I'm not using -- there was a problem having a ListView inside a ScrollView), and a lot references Adapters (which I'm not using, the data needs to be massaged thoroughly before being presentable).

The LinearLayout is specified in XML. I'm adding TextViews to it in the onPostExecute of an AsyncTask in which I do the DB lookup.

I tried registering the context menu in two ways: with Activity.registerForContextMenu(TextView) and textView.setOnCreateOptionsMenuListener(new ...).

The problem is with the following part:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    ContextMenuInfo info = (ContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.delete_entry:
              // how do I get the TextView id here???
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

The ContextMenuInfo variable is null, and of no help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016569/get-view-id-from-oncontextitemselected

Comment: I actually saw it as well just after typing up this post... go figure. I spent a good few hours on Google, only to have to put my foot in my mouth now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One answer to this question came from reading [get view id from oncontextitemselected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016569/get-view-id-from-oncontextitemselected).

It's a bit hacky though, but it does work, and that's fine for now.

You do get the View variable as a parameter in the onCreateContextMenu method. It is then trivial to store that variable in some other variable with class scope that you'll be able to use in the onContextItemSelected method.

Example:

```
private TextView contextTextView = null;

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.tankbeurt_wissen, menu);
    contextTextView = (TextView) v;
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.delete_entry:
                System.out.println(contextTextView.getId()+" called this method");
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps someone as much as it helped me.