# Android Call Popup Menu

Tags: java, android, popupmenu

Im working on a simple music player for my intro to Android apps class. I want to be able to add songs to a playlist listed in my context menu. When I click on my addtoplaylist contextmenuitem I want my popup menu to appear. **How do I call my popup menu?** Also if you have some suggestions on how to populate my popup menu, rather than my for loop, that would be cool too.

I have a contextmenu listener that kind of looks like this.

```
    @Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.share:
            shareIt();
            return true;
        case R.id.Store:
            musicStore();
            return true;
        case R.id.addtoplaylist:
        // open popup menu
            return true;
        case R.id.snippet:
            snippet(tem1);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

And i have a popup menu that kind of looks like this.

```
        public void showPopup(View v) {

    int i = view.getPlaylists().size();
    ArrayList<String> playlist = view.getPlaylists();

    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v);
    MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.getMenu());
    for(int k = 0; k > i;k++){
        popup.getMenu().add(playlist.get(k));
    }

    popup.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see here [PopupMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html) 
V is just an anchor, so you can pass for instance the ListView which contains your item
Or if you really want the popupmenu to be anchored to the item have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8584345/2122876)

You get your target view like this.

```
AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo(); 
View  v = info.targetView;
```

So after call

```
showPopUp(v);
```

For your loop, I don't see a far better solution.

Answer (score -1):

the accepted question is fine, but for the for loop part you could use an iterator :)

```
for (String song : playlist) {
    popup.getMenu().add(song);
}
```